Heroku Quick Start is not creating an App from Salesforce
I am having a weird issue when I try to create a Heroku App from my Canvas App Previewer in Salesforce. I have already registered on Heroku and added my Billing details. Now I navigate to Canvas App Previewer on Salesforce and click on Heroku Quick Start.


I add all the required details including the Heroku App API Key from my Heroku Account. Now, once I click on Create, it starts processing and keeps on processing for sometime. Then finally it ends and nothing happens. The app is not created on Heroku. The app is not present on the Canvas App Previewer or anywhere else in Salesforce. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any step that I am missing.
I checked repeatedly, my Heroku App API Key is absolutely correct.

Check your F12 Dev Console to see if there's any errors. In the interim, I'll see I can reproduce.

@sfdcfox I checked the browser console. I just see the same warning being posted multiple times ---- "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab". I tried creating the app in both Chrome and Edge but still no success and the same warning in both the browsers.

I'm able to reproduce the issue as well. I'll try some troubleshooting.
